# Charge moving in circular motion

Tags: electric-current

A point charge $q$ is moving in a circular path of radius $r$ with constant linear velocity $v$. We are asked to find the current associated with this circular motion.

The solution goes like this. We fix a particular location and then calculate the time after which the charge would cross this location again,which is $\frac{2\pi r}{v}=t$. So the current will be $\frac{q}{t}$.

But here is my doubt. The definition of current is the amount of charge flowing per unit time $=\frac{q}{t}$. Here the same amount of charge $q$ flows always. So no matter what the time interval $t$ is, $q$ is always fixed. Hence current $i$ is also changing continuously since $i=\frac{q}{t}$,$q$ is fixed but $t$ can be what ever we want. So my question is why do we have the consider the time period $T$ as it is given in the solution?It will be very helpful if my wrong concepts get cleared.

Comment: In any current in a wire the charge q which passes at one point is always the same in constant current, every second the same amount of q passes , if you wait 2 seconds 2 times q will pass.

Comment: But as q is constant and t varies, $i=\frac{q}{t}$ also depends on t,so how do you talk about constant current?

Answer (score 1):

The concept of current is meaningful when the circling period $T$ of the charge $q$ is much smaller than the current measuring time.

For example, saying that the ampere meter need $0.1$ second to count the charge pass-by a cross-section of the circuit, and period of the charge circular motion is $0.001$ second. Therefore the meter read $10 q$ during the measuring period. The `steady current` is then defined as $ i = \frac{10 q}{0.1s} = 100q / s$.

On the other hand, if the circular period is $1s$ . Under this case, the current is not well defined. We then have to use current density $\vec j(\vec r, t)$:
$$
   \vec j(\vec r, t) = q \, \vec v\, \delta^3(\vec r-\vec r'(t)) 
$$
where $\vec r'(t)$ is the location of the charge at time $t$.

Comment: I think i failed to explain my doubt, i just want to know why take $T$ instead of a variable $t$?

Comment: Your definition of current is not accurate. Current is the amount of charge flowing through a fixed cross-section per unit time, $i = \frac{\Delta q}{\Delta t}$. I am not use $t$ or $T$, but the opening time of the Ampere meter $\Delta t$, then ask how many charges passed by during this opening time.

Comment: In that case,the ammeter measuring time is not given to us,so is the solution theh gave wrong?

Comment: The time scale is always important in physics consideration. When we deal with electron moving, mostly it is in fast moving status, typically 0.1 light speed. That's why we usually treat circular electron motion as a steady current.

But, for both case, the formulation of current density is always applicable.

Answer (score 0):

The definition $i=\frac{q}{t}$ is wrong or to short, the meaning is the amount of scourge passing a point in a fixed time is the current, if you take half the time half the charge will pass, if you take 10 times the time 10 times as much charge will pass. So best think of the time asa short time intervall the easiest is to measure the church passing in 1 second, so 1A=1C/s .So  if your $\frac{2}{}==1s$ you have a current of q/1s
if  $\frac{2}{}=0,1s your current will be 10q/s
too this t is a precise time in s if you measure v in m/s and r in m . so the t in the formula is determined bei r and v and not a variable time.